# Two Aggregate Totals in One Group

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I wrote a query in **MongoDB** as follows:

```
db.getCollection('student').aggregate(
[
  {
      $match: { "student_age" : { "$ne" : 15 } }
  },
  {
      $group: 
      {
        _id: "$student_name", 
        count: {$sum: 1},
        sum1: {$sum: "$student_age"}
      }
  }     
])
```

In others words, I want to fetch the count of students that aren't 15 years old and the summary of their age. The query works fine and I get two data items.

In my application, I want to do the query by **Spring Data**.
I wrote the following code:

```
Criteria where = Criteria.where("AGE").ne(15);
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(where),
                Aggregation.group().sum("student_age").as("totalAge"),
                count().as("countOfStudentNot15YearsOld"));
```

When this code is run, the output query will be:

```
"aggregate" : "MyDocument", "pipeline" : 
    [           { "$match"   { "AGE" : { "$ne" : 15 } } }, 
                { "$group" : { "_id" : null, "totalAge" : { "$sum" : "$student_age" } } }, 
                { "$count" : "countOfStudentNot15YearsOld" }], 
                  "cursor" : { "batchSize" : 2147483647 }
```

Unfortunately, the result is only `countOfStudentNot15YearsOld` item.

I want to fetch the result like my native query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your're asking to return the grouping for both "15" and "not 15" as a result then you're looking for the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator which will allow a "branching" based on conditional evaluation.

From the "shell" content you would use it like this:

```
db.getCollection('student').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "countFiteen": { 
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$student_age", 15 ] }, 1, 0 ]
      }
    },
    "countNotFifteen": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$ne": [ "$student_age", 15 ] }, 1, 0 ]
      }
    },
     "sumNotFifteen": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$ne": [ "$student_age", 15 ] }, "$student_age", 0 ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So you use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to perform a logical test, in this case whether the `"student_age"` in the current document being considered is `15` or not, then you can return a numerical value in response which is `1` here for "counting" or the actual field value when that is what you want to send to the accumulator instead. In short it's a "ternary" operator or `if/then/else` condition ( which in fact can be shown in the more expressive form with keys ) you can use to test a condition and decide what to return.

For the spring mongodb implementation you use [`ConditionalOperators.Cond`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ConditionalOperators.Cond.html) to construct the same BSON expressions:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.*;

ConditionalOperators.Cond isFifteen = ConditionalOperators.when(new Criteria("student_age").is(15))
   .then(1).otherwise(0);

ConditionalOperators.Cond notFifteen = ConditionalOperators.when(new Criteria("student_age").ne(15))
        .then(1).otherwise(0);

ConditionalOperators.Cond sumNotFifteen = ConditionalOperators.when(new Criteria("student_age").ne(15))
        .thenValueOf("student_age").otherwise(0);


GroupOperation groupStage =  Aggregation.group()
        .sum(isFifteen).as("countFifteen")
        .sum(notFifteen).as("countNotFifteen")
        .sum(sumNotFifteen).as("sumNotFifteen");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupStage);
```

So basically you just extend off of that logic, using `.then()` for a "constant" value such as `1` for the "counts", and `.thenValueOf()` where you actually need the "value" of a field from the document, so basically equal to the `"$student_age"` as shown for the common shell notation.

Since [`ConditionalOperators.Cond`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ConditionalOperators.Cond.html) shares the `AggregationExpression` interface, this can be used with `.sum()` in the form that accepts an `AggregationExpression` as opposed to a string. This is an improvement on past releases of spring mongo which would require you to perform a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage so there were actual document properties for the evaluated expression prior to performing a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

---

If all you want is to replicate the original query for spring mongodb, then your mistake was using the `$count` aggregation stage rather than appending to the `group()`:

```
Criteria where = Criteria.where("AGE").ne(15);
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(where),
                Aggregation.group()
                    .sum("student_age").as("totalAge")
                    .count().as("countOfStudentNot15YearsOld")
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.There is a question: Does your solution have any performance issue? Because in my query in the shell, I have one match expression and in your approach, there are three conditions that are the same.

Comment: @Sam Your query **only** selects documents for a given age. There's no match expression here because your question is explicitly asking for one to not exist. For "performance" it's far better to simply run "two" queries and apply the "count" on the cursor result, rather than force count through the aggregation framework

Comment: My mean was this line: `$match: { "student_age" : { "$ne" : 15 } }`. I have some "where clauses" (I have heavy background on Relational DB, so my dictionary is near them) and after I want SUM, COUNT of them. Also, I didn't understand: **apply the "count" on the cursor result** , can you explain more?

Comment: @Sam It's very simple. In the collection there are matches that "are" 15 and ones that "are not" fifteen. In order to count **both** you cannot include a filter condition that excludes **one** of them. Instead we "conditionally accumulate" rather than "exclude". The sum of the two "counts" here is equal to the total entries in the collection. Should not be hard to follow, and that is the question that you asked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. I don't want both of 15 and not students. I have a simple condition: **Students that are 15 years old** and want two aggregation function: some of their age(students with not 15 age) and count of them(students with not 15 age)

Comment: @Sam Something really is lost in translation there. The way you named the property in your attempt is what made me think you were asking for something completely different. If I understand you now ( this time ) then the correct statement is what I just added to the end of the answer. Basically you put the `count()` "pipeline stage" when you actually wanted the `.count()` **operator**. Which is `{ "$sum": 1 }`

Comment: I apologize because I made a mistake in naming the variable, and I edited my question. Your solution is correct. Thanks.